# In query variables replacement error

Tags: java, sql, db2

I am using SQL variable replacements, and I am getting the following errors:

```
 at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:408)
        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.setValue(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:3532)
        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.setString(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:3211)
        at queries.RunQueryDB2.runNameAccount(RunQueryDB2.java:237)
```

The trace brings me to this code section,

```
stmt.setString( 1, name[0]);
stmt.setString( 2, name[1]);
stmt.setString( 3, name[2]);
```

which references this SQL variable replacement:

```
nameToAcctQuery="SELECT DISTINCT a.Acnum"
                    + "FROM table c, table p, table a "
                    + "WHERE c.First= '?.toUpperCase()' "
                    + "AND c.Mid= '?.toUpperCase()' "
                    + "AND c.Last= '?.toUpperCase()' "
                    + "AND p.Pol= a.pol"
                    + "AND p.name= c.name";
```

I use this format in many other queries, and I can not, for the life of me, figure out why I am getting an error in my variable replacement. Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the inner exception of the SQLException being thrown?   The error could be because you don't have a blank space at the end of the second-to-last line.

Comment: jesus... how did i miss that? i looked at it like 45 times. thank you. that is all.

Comment: You're wrapping the bind placeholders (`?`) within single quotes, does that really work? Maybe it's a special syntax for DB2.

Comment: that is needed because the field in the DB is cast as characters.

Comment: Does DB2 really have a function called `.toUpperCase()` that can be called like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
stmt.setString( 1, name[0].toUpperCase());
stmt.setString( 2, name[1].toUpperCase());
stmt.setString( 3, name[2].toUpperCase());
```

And your query like this (DB2 doesn't know the `toUpperCase` function):

```
nameToAcctQuery="SELECT DISTINCT a.Acnum"
                + "FROM table c, table p, table a "
                + "WHERE c.First= ? "
                + "AND c.Mid= ? "
                + "AND c.Last= ? "
                + "AND p.Pol= a.pol"
                + "AND p.name= c.name";
```

Answer (score 0):

As given by Taballeman, the problem is not the variable replacement, it is the missing space between the last character and the " on this lin

```
+ "AND p.Pol= a.pol"
```